# Efficiency of IO lists in elixir/erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have read about the efficiency of IO lists. However I am still not able to wrap my head around it.

1. How exactly is nesting of IO list more efficient than concatenating
   strings.
2. How exactly is IO list more efficient when there are a lot of repeating words.

I had used [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/elixir-and-io-lists-part-1-building-output-efficiently/)  link for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I will use Erlang syntax because it is how it is done in BEAM VM even in Elixir.

1. If you have two lists `LM` and `LN` of length `M` and `N`. Then appending `LM ++ LN` is `O(M)` operation. `[LM|LN]` is `O(1)` operation. If you have two binaries `BM` and `BN` then `<<BM/binary, BN/binary>>` is `O(M+N)` operation and `[BM|BN]` (Yes, it is valid `io_list`.) is still `O(1)` operation.
2. Repeating the same word `W` of length `W` regardless it is list or binary, repeating `N` times using `lists:duplicate(N, W)` is `O(N)` operation and it consumes `O(N)` additional memory i.e. whole memory is `O(N+W)`. If you would do flattening it would take `O(N*W)` time and it consumes `O(N*W)` memory.

Example: you can make `2^31` long list of `x` using this (Do not enter it in shell!):

```
lists:foldl(fun(_, X) -> [X|X] end, "x", lists:seq(1, 30)).
```

And it will take 30 times of time of `[_|_]` operation and consumes 31*2*8B i.e. 496B of memory (on 64b platform and a half on 32b). If you would do it as binary it would take over 2GB of memory and 32GB as a flat list (on 64b and 16GB on 32b). Good luck with this.

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot but could you please elaborate  the complexity analysis  of the two points ?